how to disable window snapping from top panel?
I just installed a fresh install of Ubuntu 24.04 and then I noticed some problems with windows snapping. Snapping worked fine when I dragged windows using the top panel (the panel where the clock and application tray are placed, not the title bar), but then I faced some problems when I accidentally double-clicked on the top panel.
Somehow the memory usage increases rapidly within seconds (maybe there is a memory leak?). Once that happens, windows snapping doesn't work anymore. I need to restart Ubuntu to get it working again.
Is there a way to disable this behavior (snapping using the top panel) or just disable window snapping? Is anyone having this problem at the moment?
memory usage before double-clicking the panel:

high memory usage after double-clicking the panel:


First, what does top show when you use SHIFT+M to sort by memory use? This will give you a better idea of what process is using your memory.

I think it's sorted because I don't run anything but gnome shell, system monitor, and top terminal. i tried doing the same with shift+m ​​in terminal, gnome shell stays on top when memory usage increases.


After some searching on the internet, I just found out that this is caused by the enhanced tiling feature enabled in the settings. If you run into this problem, just turn it off and you'll be fine.

Answer moved here from OP's question.
This extension can be toggled utilizing gnome's extension manager which can be installed with:
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-manager

Ubuntu Tiling Assistant can be turned off while still maintaining snap functionality without this behavior. This should work until a bug fix is released.

Beware that this solution doesn't seem to take into account that disabling Tiling Assistant also disables the hotkeys for snapping (Super+arrows). You will be able to snap only by dragging the windows to the edges.

Left and Right still work for me even with Tiling extension disabled.  I suspect that if you really want to tweak things in detail, you can use dconf-editor to enable/disable individual features.
